# Next.js - How to send Data-Object while redirecting from api-route without query-params?

Tags: javascript, web, next.js

I am creating this app using Next.js and their api-routes and I have an auth-flow that:

1. redirects and let's the user log in with a company Social-Login and redirects to:
2. my `/api/getaccesstoken`, which uses the query params to get a User-Object and an AccessToken
3. then it goes back to `/`, currently using `res.redirect("/")`

How can I send some User Info and additional data **without** using query params ?

Comment: Have you considered using cookies?

Comment: Oh wow, that went completely over my head, thank you!